# Python, loops with changeable parts of filenames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of very similar commands which all look like this (df means pandas dataframe):

```
df1_part1=...
df1_part2=...
...
df1_part5=...
df2_part1=...
```

I would like to make a loop for it, as follows:

```
for i in range(1,5):
for j in range(1,5):
df%i_part%j=...
```

Of course, it doesn't work with %. But is has to be some easy way to do it, I suppose.
Could You help me please?

Comment: Assign dataframe to a dict instead of assigning to variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of the following options:

1. Create a dictionary which maps the your df and access it by the name of the dataframe:

```
mapping = {"df1_part1": df1_part1, "df1_part2": df1_part2}
for i in range(1,5):
    for j in range(1,5):
        mapping[f"df{i}_part{j}"] = ...
```

2. Use `globals` to access dynamically your variables:

```
df1_part1=...
df1_part2=...
...
df1_part5=...
df2_part1=...

for i in range(1,5):
    for j in range(1,5):
        globals()[f"df{i}_part{j}"] = ...
```

Comment: avoid using global variables when un-necessary, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874946/is-there-any-disadvantage-to-declare-a-variable-global

Comment: What is an alternative to global variables in my case? I cannot define a list of files, it would be to long. I not only have files with numbers in it on the left side, there are much more on the right side.

Comment: I still think that it is strange that there is no simple solution. In SAS it is enought to write df%i_part%j=... and everything is fine. Macro variables make it possible.

Comment: There is a simple solution: use an appropriate data structure like a dictionary rather than digging in the innards of variable names with `globals`.

Comment: I have commands like verb_kd_top3_z =top3[top3.kd.isin(top3_zl_kd)==True] and I dont' want to manually create lists or dictionaries of all of the files.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to collect your pandas dataframes in a list of lists and iterate over that list instead of trying dynamically parse your python code.

```
df1_part1=...
df1_part2=...
...
df1_part5=...
df2_part1=...

dflist = [[df1_part1, df1_part2, df1_part3, df1_part4, df1_part5],
          [df2_part1, df2_part2, df2_part3, df2_part4, df2_part5]]
for df in dflist:
    for df_part in df:
        # do something with df_part
```

Comment: This solution would not help much. Actually I have in each command many places where the same number is a part of some file. The list of lists would be very long.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this process is part of data preparation, I would like to mention that you should try to work with "data preparation pipelines" whenever it is possible. Otherwise, the code will be a huge mess to read after a couple of months.

There are several ways to deal with this problem.

A dictionary is the most straightforward way to deal with this.

```py
df_parts = {
            'df1' : {'part1': df1_part1, 'part2': df1_part2,...,'partN': df1_partN},
            'df2' : {'part1': df1_part1, 'part2': df1_part2,...,'partN': df2_partN},
            '...' : {'part1': ..._part1, 'part2': ..._part2,...,'partN': ..._partN},
            'dfN' : {'part1': dfN_part1, 'part2': dfN_part2,...,'partN': dfN_partN},
           }

# print parts from `dfN`
for val in for df_parts['dfN'].values():
    print(val)

# print part1 for all dfs
for df in df_parts.values():
    print(df['part1'])

# print everything
for df in df_parts:
    for val in df_parts[df].values():
        print(val)
```

The good thing with this approach is that you can iterate through the whole dictionary, but you don't include `range` which may be confusing later. Also, it is better to assign every df_part directly to a dict instead of assigning `N*N` variables which may be used once or twice. In this case you can just use *1 variable* and re-assign it as you progress:

```py
# code using df1_partN
df1 = df_parts['df1']['partN']
# stuff to do
# happy? checkpoint
df_parts['df1']['partN'] = df1
```

Comment: It's a lot to code, so I don't save any time at the end. The problem is that I have 5 different types of file names with numbers in it, not only df... So I need 5 dictionaries and then I have to rewrite all commands. It is easier simply to copy and paste and change the numbers manually. I can do this faster.

Comment: I can agree that the problem is the "bad" data preparation, but it was not my idea to do it this way. And still I have to work with it, I am not authorized to change the name conventions.