# How to make functions variables public, they are not in a class C++

Tags: c++, variables, public

I would like to know how I can make a function's variable public to other functions.

Example:

```
void InHere
{
    int one = 1; // I want to be public
}
int main()
{
    InHere(); // This will set int one = 1
    one = 2; // If the variable is public, I should be able to do this
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this? The only things I find when searching is for classes, as you can see nothing is in a class and I don't want them to be in one.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: C++ doesn't work this way. If you want the variables to be accessible beyond a single function, they need to live in a class or a namespace. There's no way for something other than `InHere` to know about `one`.

Comment: Public variables to other functions are global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable defined locally to a function is generally inaccessible outside that function unless the function explicitly supplies a reference/pointer to that variable.

One option is for the function to explicitly return a reference or pointer to that variable to the caller.    That gives undefined behaviour if the variable is not `static`, as it does not exist after the function returns.

```
int &InHere()
{
     static int one = 1;
     return one;
}

void some_other_func()
{
     InHere() = 2;
}
```

This causes undefined behaviour if the variable `one` is not `static` since, as far as the program as a whole is concerned, the variable only comes into existence whes `InHere()` is called and ceases to exist as it returns  (so the caller receives a dangling reference - a reference to something that no longer exists).

Another option is for the function to pass a pointer or reference to the variable as an argument to another function.

```
 void do_something(int &variable)
 {
      variable = 2;
 }     

 int InHere()
 {
      int one = 1;
      do_something(one);
      std::cout << one << '\n';    // will print 2
 }
```

The downside is that this only provides access to functions CALLED BY `InHere()`.   Although the variable does not need to be `static` in this case, the variable still ceases to exist as `InHere()` returns   (so if you want to combine option 1 and option 2 in some way, the variable needs to be `static`)

A third option is to define the variable at file scope, so it has static storage duration  (i.e. its lifetime is not related to the function);

```
 int one;
 void InHere()
 {
      one = 1;
 }

 void another_function()
 {
      one = 2;
 }

 int main()
 {
     InHere();
        // one has value 1

     some_other_function();
        // one has value 2
 }
```

A global variable can be accessed in any function that has visibility of a declaration of the variable.   For example, we could do

```
 extern int one;             // declaration but not definition of one

 int one;                    // definition of one.  This can only appear ONCE into the entire program

 void InHere()
 {
      one = 1;
 }
```

And, in other source file

```
 extern int one;         // this provides visibility to one but relies on it
                         //   being defined in another source file 

 void another_function()
 {
      one = 2;
 }

 int main()
 {
     InHere();
        // one has value 1

     some_other_function();
        // one has value 2
 }
```

Be careful with that though - there are numerous down-sides of global/static variables, to the extent they are usually considered VERY BAD programming technique.    Have a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874946/is-there-any-disadvantage-to-declare-a-variable-global) (and pages linked to from there) for a description of some of the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the variable as a global variable. Then you can access it from other functions.

```
int one;
void InHere()
{
    one = 1; // I want to be public
}
int main()
{
    InHere(); // This will set int one = 1
    one = 2; // If the variable is public, I should be able to do this
    return 0;
}
```

if you want it inside a class, then try the code below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class My_class
{
    // private members
public: // public section
    // public members, methods or attributes
    int one;
    void InHere();
};

void My_class::InHere()
{
    one = 1; // it is public now
}
int main()
{
    My_class obj;
    obj.InHere(); // This will set one = 1
    cout<<obj.one;
    obj.one = 2; // If the variable is public, I should be able to do this
    cout<<obj.one;
    return 0;
}
```